# ¿Como puedo solucionar el Androind Manifest? MainActivity, aplicattion name, @mipmap/ic_launcher

Tags: java, android-studio, flutter, dart, android-manifest

Tengo este error desde ayer, no eh podido ejecutar mi app, ya actualice todo, Programo en Flutter y Dart en Android Studio, tengo las últimas versiones, pero no sé qué pasa anteriormente ya eh programado en Android Studio y en Flutter y Dart, pero nunca me había pasado esto, de hecho... este problema me pasa con todos los proyectos, creo que algo me falta por instalar o algo falta de actualizar, porque no se, llevo tres dias asi sin encontrar una solucion a este problema, ojala me puedan a ayudar.

Al abrir o crear un nuevo proyecto todo esta bien pero al abrir esas carpetas, todome lo marca en tojo y ya no se que hacer, menciono que soy nuevo en esto, voy en bachiller, si tienen alguna solución, explíquenme bien por favor.

[image: Error en la Manifest]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ameself">
   <application
        android:label="ameself"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Tambien tengo estos problemas en la estructura del proyecto, creo que tambien influyen.

Comment: Verifica todo eso que tienes en rojo. ¿Existe todo eso en tu proyecto? ¿Cómo estás declarando tu `MainActivity`? Los mensajes de error son todos muy claros.

Comment: Por favor coloca los errores como texto en tu pregunta. Haz click en [edit] para editarla y agregarlos. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y [example]. Saludos

Comment: Si puedes ejecutar el proyecto, olvídate de esos errores. Cuando abres los archivos nativos de Android o IOS en Android Studio, cuando estás en Flutter, te lo marca todo en rojo. No te preocupes. No hay ningún fallo. Si no te inicia el proyecto, deberás poner que error arroja la consola.

Comment: Lo que podrias intentar hacer es borrar la carpeta android y hacer un ```flutter create .``` dentro del proyecto. Esto te va a volver a construir la carpeta de android. No te olvides después de eso hacer ```flutter clean``` y ```flutter pub get``` por si acaso tienes paquetes que agregan cosas al proyecto Android de flutter.